# Default hour to 00 using flatpickr

Tags: javascript, dom, timepicker, flatpickr

I'm using an inline time picker (12 hour format) using the flatpickr library.

From scouring their documentation, they only support the range [1:12] for the visual control for selecting hour, but I need to get it to [0:11].

What I've tried is setting **min** and **max** attributes on the input corresponding to the hour and then setting 0 as default hour on the flatpickr options, but, while the DOM was updated accordingly, it seems to be ignored (i.e. the control still defaults to 12 and the selectable range is [1:12]).

```
time_picker = flatpickr("#time_picker", {
            enableTime: true,
            noCalendar: true,
            dateFormat: "G:i",
            time_24hr: false,
            inline: true,
            defaultHour: 0
        });

$(".flatpickr-hour").attr({
    "max" : 11,
    "min" : 0
});
```

Is there a functional way to get this to work?

Comment: You can use their required `1..12` and adjust time as you see fit afterwards. Im not seeing a problem here. You can subtract one from the return value of theirs im sure easily enough. Have you read the docs?

Comment: I'm explicitly asking about displaying the value as 0 instead of 12, not changing the model behind it. If that's unclear, I will edit the question.

Comment: Its not unclear. But it does seem pointless and probable error prone. Why would you change the source on a `x - 1` operation?

Comment: *it seems to be ignored* because they wrote an api where user-input out of bounds is corrected. Its their api. They make the rules. I doubt you want to change their source. Cant you easily enough put a Base 1 hour as data on instantiation, and calculate `h - 1` after the fact, to get Base 0?

Comment: I did want to obtain this flexibility, so thanks for the pointer on contributing to the API. I might very well do that. Backend is not an issue whatsoever in my case, design is. The design is to have that control start at 0 and end at 11.

Comment: Listen. h = 13 for 1pm. Now you havent said as much. You want h = 12 to be h = 11. So you subtract 1. Not seing a *contributing to the API*. ......... If the *design is to have that control start at 0 and end at 11* then you can do this. You just add +1 to respect the api you rely upon.

Comment: That is military time on hour is Base 0

Comment: I think we're having a miscommunication moment. I don't want h=12 to be 11, but 0. I don't care about the backlying API at all, just the visual design, nor do I want to change AM/PM to full 24-hour format.

Comment: Ok so it seems you want to represent time 24, time 24 is military time. `0` is midnight hour. `12` is 12 noon ... I cant say to know your api. However no changes are necessary if you convert before and after.